# Update Record If Exists (Without Key) If Not Insert

Tags: mysql, sql, exists, insert-update

Suppose I have a table `user_keys` with `id, username, key`. I need a query which will receive two parameters: `username, key`. I want to update record (only column `key`) if it exists (means that record with the incoming `username` already exists) if not then just insert new row with both parameters.

Well, I have tried a few things, here is one of them

```
if not exists (select * from user_keys where username='uname') then
insert into user_keys
(username, token)
values( 'uname','token')

else
update...
```

But it does not work. Any idea how to achieve?

Comment: You're looking for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Googling that will set you on the correct path. The idea is that you have a unique key (username in your case) and you're trying to insert. If the insert fails, you use MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach to update the record otherwise.

Comment: So, I have to set Unique constraint on username, right?

Comment: Exactly, you need to make it unique.